# CDF of two exponential variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

I want to know if my CDF calculation is correct.

> Let $X,Z$ be independent random variables with exponential distribution and parameter $\gamma_x,\gamma_z$. Compute $P(Z+X<t)$

\begin{align*}P(Z+X<t)&=P(Z<t-x,X=x)\\
&=\int\limits_{0}^\infty \int\limits_{0}^{t-x} \gamma_xe^{-\gamma_x t}\gamma_ze^{-\gamma_zm}\mathrm{d}m\mathrm{d}x=\int\limits_{0}^\infty \gamma_z\gamma_xe^{-\gamma_x t}\int\limits_{0}^{t-x} e^{-\gamma_zm}\mathrm{d}m\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int\limits_{0}^\infty \gamma_z\gamma_xe^{-\gamma_x t} \left[\frac{-e^{-\gamma_zm}}{\gamma_z}\right]_{0}^{t-x}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int\limits_{0}^\infty \gamma_xe^{-\gamma_x t} (1-e^{-\gamma_z(t-x)})\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\gamma_x\int\limits_{0}^\infty e^{-\gamma_x t}-e^{-\gamma_zx-\gamma_zt-\gamma_x t}\mathrm{d}x=\gamma_x\left[\frac{-e^{-\gamma_x t}}{\gamma_x}\right]_0^\infty+\gamma_xe^{-\gamma_zt-\gamma_x t}\left[\frac{e^{-\gamma_zx}}{\gamma_x}\right]_0^\infty \mathrm{d}x\\
&=1-e^{-t(\gamma_z+\gamma_x )}\qquad t\geq 0\\
\end{align*}

I don't know how to check such things. What is a good way?

Comment: I can tell you that what you just wrote is wrong: you have actually written the CDF for the minimum, not the sum. You can see this because the CDF of the sum should be smaller than the CDF of the separate terms (since both r.v.s are nonnegative) but in fact your CDF is larger. But I'm not sure at a quick glance where the mistake is.

Comment: @Ian ok thanks. Just a final question. Is the first step correct $P(Z+X<t)=P(Z<t+x,X=x)$?

Comment: Strictly speaking no, but if you apply independence and interpret $P (X=x) $ as its density then you get the correct result. This is just the total probability formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pdf for $x$ and $z$ are:

$\frac{1}{\lambda_x}e^{\frac{-x}{\lambda_x}}$ and $\frac{1}{\lambda_z}e^{\frac{-z}{\lambda_z}}$

Let $Y=X+Z$

In order for $y=x+z$ we need $X=x$ and $Z=y-x$

The probability that $X=x$ and $Z=y-x$ is the product of the pdfs at these two values, i.e. $P(Y=X+Z) = \frac{1}{\lambda_x}e^{\frac{-x}{\lambda_x}} \cdot \frac{1}{\lambda_z}e^{\frac{-(y-x)}{\lambda_z}}$

Now integrate over all possible values of $x$. Note that $x$ cannot be greater than $y$ since the sum of $x$ and $z$ is $y$

$P(Y=y) = \int_{0}^{y} \frac{1}{\lambda_x}e^{\frac{-x}{\lambda_x}} \cdot \frac{1}{\lambda_z}e^{\frac{-(y-x)}{\lambda_z}}dx$

$P(Y=y) = \frac{e^{\frac{-y}{\lambda_x}}-e^{\frac{-y}{\lambda_z}}}{\lambda_x-\lambda_z}$

My notation is a bit sloppy. $P(Y=y)$ is the pdf of $Y$. Now integrate the pdf to get the cdf

$\text{CDF}(y)=\int_0^t \frac{e^{\frac{-y}{\lambda_x}}-e^{\frac{-y}{\lambda_z}}}{\lambda_x-\lambda_z}dy = \frac{\frac{1}{\lambda_x}(1-e^{\frac{t}{\lambda_x}})-\frac{1}{\lambda_z}(1-e^{\frac{t}{\lambda_z}})}{\frac{1}{\lambda_x}-\frac{1}{\lambda_z}}$

Comment: I would advise not to use the notation $P(Y=y)$ for the PDF $f_Y(y)$ because the values of a PDF are not probabilities, they are probabilities per unit quantity. This is why PDF's can exceed $1$ but CDF's cannot because they are true probabilities.

Comment: Further, if you do want to talk about the event $Y=y$ for a continuous RV, then its probability is zero, so....